# Creating a Line graph from data within an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python

I have data from an excel spreadsheet concerning the UK economy but how do i make a line graph from said information? This is what i have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


df = (pd.read_excel('Uk_data.xlsx').dropna())
dataset = df.to_dict()


print(df[0:])



plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
plt.style.use('seaborn')

plt.title("UK GDP Since 2017")
plt.show()



print(df.head())
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of that `df`. Like do a `print(df.head())` and paste here. (After pasting, highlight what was pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor. It will indent with 4 spaces and your white space will be preserved). It's difficult to suggest code for a graph without knowing the data structure.

Comment: [The pyplot lib has a lot of grahing methods](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html). The most commonly used are _plot_ and _scatter_. Take a look on the documentation.

Comment: do you want me to copy the excel file im using?

Comment: You need to share the output of the code as well.